# What is the best way to store user input using prompt() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Basically, if you had a program that asked for a pet's name, in what way would you store a user's input so that the program wouldn't distinguish between "Fluffy" , "fluffy", and "FLUFFY"?

Comment: kind of a subjective question - but for the most part you would just save the result after mutating it to an 'agreed' state - usually you'll see '.trim().toLowerCase()' called on the string and it is stored that way - so anyone else entering a new value would always only compare the lower-cased, trimmed version of the value.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this is in fact a trivial question, as someone would just need to convert inputs to lower casing or upper casing, and doesn't necessarily have to do with how you store the variable initially.